# PG Admin 4 не видит тип SERIAL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

я создал базу данных PostgreSQL и в качестве СУБД использовал Intellij IDEA,во многих таблицах на первичном ключе у меня стоял тип SERIAL,но теперь когда я захожу в PG Admin он не видит этот тип  и при добавлении значений в таблицу у поля id обнаруживаются значения null ,хотя id это первичный ключ и на нем висит констрейн NOT NULL ,вопрос,как такое возможно? В Intellij IDEA создавал таблицу таким образом :

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
dob DATE NOT NULL ,
sex VARCHAR(1)
```

);
ALTER SEQUENCE customers_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000000;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: пример таблицы]

Comment: `SERIAL` не требует `sequence`, `default` и `nextval`

Comment: Точнее, он их сам создаст, так что, вероятно, PGADMIN тебе эти авто-созданные и показывает. Чтобы там значение генерировалось, нужно не вставлять в эту колонку ничего и не указывать её в `INSERT`

Comment: Я вставлял данные через jdbc игнорируя поле id, так как помнил,что база сама их генерирует,но в итоге получил null айдишники

Comment: Думаю, что где-то косяк со схемами (schema). JDBC вставляет в одну схему, где таблица не была обновлена и использует старое определение таблицы без `serial`, а через IJ IDEA и PGADMIN ты смотришь на другую схему (`rest_schema`). Ну или транзакцию с изменением таблицы не закомитил.

Comment: Посмотрел еще раз,косяка со схемами не нашел. Подумал,что пг админ в принципе не поддерживает сериал,но нет,создал новую тестовую таблицу и он отлично инкрементирует

Comment: Хотя нет,похоже вы правы,он создал тестовую таблицу,а также две другие(Customers и Employees) в схеме public. Не знаете как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: При коннекте можно указывать дефолтную схему `...&currentSchema=my_schema` или при создании таблиц можно указывать в какой схеме создавать `create table my_schema.my_table` или (если используется файл для создания бд) можно в начале файла `SET search_path TO my_schema`;